# How to make ssh read public key from other path (in windows)

Tags: ssh, path, window

Currently i can connect to my linux remote server with "`ssh myusername@ipaddress`"
ssh will read my public key by default from C:/users/myaccount/.ssh/identity.pub

My question is:

- How to instruct ssh to read my public key to let say  C:/privatekey/identity.pub

My effort:

- i've try  `ssh myusername@ipaddress C:/privatekey/identity.pub`

> error : syntax error: "<" expected

- im sure there are other proper way to instruct ssh to read public key path.

Thanks in advance.

p/s : i run `ssh myusername@ipaddress` from window 7 cmd with `rsync/cygdrive`

**Answer**

Well i just find the answer, to change it path from default C:/users/myaccount/.ssh we have to change path from ssh.exe file(if you can run ssh command at your windows cmd you should have this file).

what i do is i create a batch file like below

```
//instructPathtoSSH.exe.bat
@echo off
set HOME=C:/privatekey/
set RSYNC_RSH=ssh.exe
ssh username@ipaddress
```

run it from cmd and ssh will run from path specified

Comment: was my question is unclear? i can explain more about it

Answer (score 0):

You can define the location of the ssh-key with the -i option in the command line. This would look like this.

ssh myusername@ipaddress -i C:/privatekey/identity.pub

But please check if the path to the file can be provided like that inside the cygwin environment. I can remember that there are things slightly different.

Another way is that you create a config file for ssh. That config file is usually (under linux) located at ~/.ssh/config and i would assume that it will be in your case under C:/users/myaccount/.ssh/config. This file might not exist yet. But when you create it you can specify the configuration per host. The content of the file could look like this.

Host ipaddress
    IdentityFile C:/privatekey/identity.pub

Then you can connect without defining the public key file path in the command line. Again, please check how you need to specify the path to the key file in the cygwin environment.